# COM process runs up but only IUnknown is queryable

Tags: c++, com

I am a bit of a weird situation. I've created a COM server (.exe module) and registered it; I can see the entries in my registry.

This server registers a class id, and when the process starts up it registers an object against that id which supports a custom interface `ISomething`:

```
//rough pseudo code
MyClass : public ISomething { ... };

main(){
 ::CoInitialize(NULL);
 MyClass obj;
 CoRegisterClassObject(ClassId, (ISomething *)&obj, ...);
 ...
}
```

When I try to co-create the clsid with IUnknown from a test-app, the COM process runs up and I get a non-NULL IUnknown pointer.

But if I try to cocreate using `ISomething` I get `E_NOINTERFACE`.

Please note this code setup is tried and tested over many modules, it's basically copy-pasted. So I believe the issue is a registry/configuration one.

I'm on a "clean" dev PC so the only thing I've registered is the COM .exe linked to `ClassId`.

Is the issue that I also need to have `ISomething` registered? **Roman R** mentions proxy stubs in his answer (before I edited my question) and I wonder if that's the problem... does each interface need to be registered as well as the component's class ID?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `QueryInterface` and see why it returns `E_NOINTERFACE`. Does your call even reach the server? Or is the `QueryInterface` implementation mishandling the interface request? Are you sure that you're using the right interface GUID?

Comment: Run it in the debugger, put a breakpoint on it.

Comment: You can look at the object's type library (if it publishes one, which it doesn' t have to , but typically they do)

Comment: for each(GUID g in AllGuids)
{
}

Comment: @Ben on what precisely? I can see the COM process is being run up (good sign) but after that I don't have a clue what's happening

Comment: Are your running the COM server process in the debugger? Or not?

Comment: Here's a clue: Put _CrtDebugBreak() in your QueryInterface implementation. Then you can "Attach" to the process at the relevant point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your COM server hosted by .EXE is out-of-process server. Consuming its interfaces you access the server from another process: you don't talk to the server directly, instead you talk to proxy the COM subsystem created for you.

Client process: Your client code -> Proxy -> (Magic)

Server process: (Magic) -> Stub -> Your server code

Well, proxy/stub is a part of magic too, but I separated them to help understanding that client code is interfaced to something tangible but not yet real server.

Proxy, stub and the rest of the magic create an imitation of the COM interfaces your client code requests and then forward the calls to real server, then take data back. They can only do interfaces that are "marshalable", for which marshaling code exists, where proxy/stub pair creation is possible.

Not every interface can be marshaled, and this finally gets us to the situation that server implements an interface, you know it for sure, and you still cannot obtain it on client side.

There are a few options how to get marshaling done, and the easiest way to accomplish the task with ATL is to make sure:

- the interface is derived from `IDispatch`, is marked `oleautomation` in the type library
- the interface is in library section of IDL code, or otherwise is included into TLB file and is visible in your EXE when inspected with OleView
- COM server (EXE) registers well and your COM object implements the interface correctly (COM_MAP entry etc)

In this case you are taking advantage of standard marshaler (also known as `PSOAInterface`) for OLE automation interfaces and you have proxy/stub pairs created for you without any additional effort.

You might want to look some code snippets up here: http://diranieh.com/ATLCOM/IDL.htm

Comment: I've reworked my question; I think your comment about proxy stubs could be the key here. I only registered the COM process, is that not sufficient? Woudl that explain that COM knows to run up the right process based on the class-id, but doesn't know how how to get the interface I ask for?

Comment: Your edit still leaves the question incomplete. You do register CLSID to make it discoverable, but this does not cover the question how to deal with the interface. Apparently it needs marshaling and if it's somcethnig custom then it does not receive marshaling for granted. `E_NOINTERFACE` suggests the COM could access the CLSID in question, the problem is exactly in the interface.

Comment: Unless a simple project setting when building would affect this, I assume all this stuff works since as mentioned, the same interface and approach is used in many of our modules. I'm basically making a new module copy-pasting our normal approach - but I don't know if the issue is my code, or merely that my dev-PC doesn't have the right stuff registered. I'm leaning to the latter.

Comment: You can simply create a new ATL EXE project usign wizard and add ATL Simple object using wizard with all defaults. Created out of process COM server should be well accessible by simplest client code. Then you would be able to compare your non-working code with this working code.

Comment: So it turns out the clue was the proxy stubs - I'd simply forgotten to register them explicitly as well as the COM server module.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling OleRun() before your call to QueryInterface().  If the object is out of process, you are only talking to the handler object.  The EXE is probably not even running.  Calling OleRun will cause it to load.  Then querying for the interface is more likely to work.